# Advice on vectorizing block-wise operations in Numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

I am trying to implement a series of statistical operations, and I need help vectorizing my code.

The idea is to extract `NxN` patches from two images, the compute a distance metric between these two patches.

To do this, first I construct the patches with the following loops:

```
params = []
for i in range(0,patch1.shape[0],1):
    for j in range(0,patch1.shape[1],1):
        window1 = np.copy(imga[i:i+N,j:j+N]).flatten()
        window2 = np.copy(imgb[i:i+N,j:j+N]).flatten()
        params.append((window1, window2))
print(f"We took {time()- t0:2.2f} seconds to prepare {len(params)/1e6} million patches.")
```

This takes about 10 seconds to complete, and I'm not overly concerned with the pre-processing time. The steps below that follow are the steps I want to optimize.

After this, in an attempt to speed up processing I used multipool to compute the actual results. The function that contains the actual computation is as follows:

```
@njit
def cauchy_schwartz(imga, imgb):
    p, _ = np.histogram(imga, bins=10)
    p = p/np.sum(p)
    q, _ = np.histogram(imgb, bins=10)
    q = q/np.sum(q)

    n_d = np.array(np.sum(p * q)) 
    d_d = np.array(np.sum(np.power(p, 2) * np.power(q, 2)))
    return -1.0 * np.log10( n_d, d_d)
```

I use this structure to process all the patches:

```
def f(param):
    return cauchy_schwartz(*param)

with Pool(4) as p:
    r = list(tqdm.tqdm(p.imap(f,params), total=len(params)))
```

I am sure there must be something much more elegant to do this, because if I send the whole 10Kpx by 10Kpx images to the `cauchy_schwartz` function it processes everything in under a second, but with my approach, even on 4 cores it takes a long time.

My mental model is how `blockproc` in matlab works - and I ended up writing this code in that pattern. I would appreciate any advice on improving the performance of this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `apply_along_axis`, you can get rid of `cauchy_schwartz`. Since you are not overly concerned with the pre-processing time, assume you have obtained the array `params` which contains the flattened patches

`params = np.random.rand(3,2,100)`

as you can see the shape of `params` is `(3,2,100)`, the three numbers 3, 2, and 100 are just randomly chosen to create an auxiliary array to demonstrate the logic of using `apply_along_axis`. 3 corresponds to the number of patches you have (determined by the patch shape and the image size), 2 corresponds to the two images, and 100 corresponds to the flattened patches. Therefore, the axes of `params` is `(idx of patches, idx of images, idx of entries of a flattened patch)`, this exactly matches the list `params` created by your code

```
params = []
for i in range(0,patch1.shape[0],1):
    for j in range(0,patch1.shape[1],1):
        window1 = np.copy(imga[i:i+N,j:j+N]).flatten()
        window2 = np.copy(imgb[i:i+N,j:j+N]).flatten()
        params.append((window1, window2))
```

With the auxiliary array `params`, here is my solution:

```
hist = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.histogram(x,bins=11)[0],2,params)
hist = hist / np.sum(hist,axis=2)[...,None]

n_d = np.sum(np.product(hist,axis=1),axis=1)
d_d = np.sum(np.product(np.power(hist,2),axis=1),axis=1)
res = -1.0 * np.log10(n_d, d_d)
```

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for, and it also helps me learn the logic.  Was just a little curious to understand why you chose 3 as the first dimension for the params in `random.rand(3,2,100)`. Let me experiment and think and try to understand this a little. But if you could help explain - it would save me guessing. In your solution is the N (window size) 3, depth 2 (for the 2 patches) and 100 samples/blocks?

Comment: @shaunakde You are welcome :) glad my answer helps you, I have updated my answer to explain the axes of the array `params`.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I came here to say that with some trial and error I was able to understand, but thank you for the update! I also learned a lot about writing good numpy code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, profile your code to identify the bottleneck. You can use https://mg.pov.lt/profilehooks/. I think the bottleneck is located in the creation of the patches since you are creating a copy of the patches for the processes. You could use less memory by passing the indices of the patches only:

```
params = []
for i in range(0,patch1.shape[0],1):
    for j in range(0,patch1.shape[1],1):
        start, end = (i,i+N), (j,j+N)
        params.append((start, end))
```

Then, assuming `imga` and `imgb` are global, you can create the patches from `cauchy_schwartz` function as shown below:

```
@njit
def cauchy_schwartz(start, end):

    a,b = start; c,d = end
    window1 = np.copy(imga[a:b, c:d]).flatten()
    window2 = np.copy(imgb[a:b, c:d]).flatten()

    # process patches window1 and window2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that is not the slow step. I'm able to Numba compile the pre-processing code. Its insignificant when compared to the slower histogram computation and patch-wise processing in the next steps. The np.copy let's me delete the original arrays from memory. I could change them to references, but it doesn't change the compute time as much.

Comment: Maybe your code causes false sharing: False sharing occurs when threads on different processors modify variables that reside on the same cache line [source](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads.html).

Comment: Interesting! Do you have any suggestions on how to measure that? Or steps I can take to mitigate it?

Comment: Maybe you could use different patch sizes (`patch1.shape` in your code). I hypothesize that a bigger patch size could lead to better performance (smaller execution time).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think you are correct in that assesment. If I pass the whole image to the function it computes it in a second. But if I pass numerous small blocks - it takes a lot longer (~120s). I am assuming this has to do with python's internal data model. I am trying to think of ways of aggregating or structuring this problem so that I can use numba's vectorize or do the whole operation using numpy. Will keep this post updated with any findings! Thank you for taking the time to help! [1/2]

Comment: Following your suggestion I did try a couple of things:
1. If I don't np.copy - the hypothesis holds. Bigger block sizes leads to better performance - even for overlapping blocks. 
2. When I do the np.copy - the runtime remains constant[2/2]